# Removing the title bar from jQueryUI Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, simplemodal

How can I remove the title bar.

I checked the API here but could not find anything.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

I noticed that other "solutions" have a cooler looking GUI then jQuery, particularly

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

However I'd like to use jQueryUI b.c. of all the resources...online API documentation, tutorials, etc.

I just need to know how to get rid of the title bar?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you hide it with css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `el` as the original element from which the dialog was created:

```
$(el).siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/N9TGd/

Note that actually removing the titlebar (per the question title) will also remove the close button, and break the ability to drag the dialog box!

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - hit F12 in browser , inspect element , and you can hide / change any part of the dialog in css or js - you asked how he knew the class of the title

Comment: @HiroProtagonist a modal is more than that - you also need an overlay panel which sits behind the modal but in front of all other content that will absorb all other user generated events.

Comment: okay...I'm sure I'll be able to detect my events..I know all about bubbling and event listeners.

Comment: I'll post a fiddle of my customization here in a bit once it is done..going to put a "glass pane" behind it...or overlay panel have you.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist watch out for things like tabIndex - you need to ensure that no other element can gain the focus.  The jQuery dialog does all this for you, at the expense of other stuff you don't need...

Answer (score 9):

There are a few options.

**Hide with CSS**
`.ui-dialog-titlebar { display: none }`

**Hide with Javascript**
This will remove the title bar when the dialog is created, but it will preserve the close button.

```
$("div").dialog({
  create: function( event, ui ) {
      var dialog = $(this).closest(".ui-dialog");
      dialog.find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            .appendTo(dialog)
            .css({
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              margin: "3px"
            });
      dialog.find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
  }
})​
```

**See demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4AuhC/52/

Comment: yes, it will now you've fixed it.  Your original assumed that the titlebar was a child of the dialog element, when it's actually a sibling.

Answer (score 5):

Add this CSS after jQuery UI's CSS.

Be careful: no more close buttons and you can't drag it anymore!

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar { display: none }
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeVvA/

If you want to keep drag and buttons, but it might not work on all themes..

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar { background: none; border: 0px solid black }​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeVvA/1/

You could probably do more just by using CSS. I'd probably play with height.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist the close buttons belong in the titlebar - where did you expect the to go if the titlebar is gone?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist it's not that simple - the close button is a descendent of the title bar.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can put remove background and remove the border.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding this to your CSS directly..

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar
{ 
   display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the route I would go.  In case he doesn't want to hide the title bar on _all_ jQuery Dialog windows he may have, the css selector could easily be made more specific `#container .ui-dialog-titlebar { ... }`.

Comment: yup.. that's right.. He can target just some of the jQuery Modals by prepending  it with a container

Comment: as with the answers that actually remove the element, this will break the drag and close functionality.  Leaving the element in place, but styled so you can't actually see it is probably the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide()
```

(Or)

```
$("#dlg").dialog({
  open: function() {
    $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the titelbar and keep the close icon using styles only, use the styles below.  It shrinks the title bar to the size of the close icon and hides it behind.  `ui-icons_6e6e6e_256x240.png` I created by lightening the `ui-icons_222222_256x240.png` image that jqueryui comes with.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header{background: none; border: none; height: 20px; width: 20px; padding: 0px; position: static; float: right; margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;}

.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header .ui-dialog-title{display: none;}

.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header .ui-button{background: none; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{margin: 0px; position: static;}

.ui-dialog .dialog.ui-dialog-content{padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-close .ui-icon{position: relative; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-state-default .ui-icon {background-image: url("/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-icons_6e6e6e_256x240.png");}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-state-hover .ui-icon {background-image: url("/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");}
```

Comment: If you want to make the entire dialog draggable, use this: $("#yourdialog").parent().draggable(); (after you create the dialog)